# Is there any way to disable automatic updates for Microsoft Edge on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, browser, updates, microsoft-edge

On one of my older test machines with Windows Update enabled, the newer Chromium-based build of Microsoft Edge has been downloaded - upon rebooting for the first time after the update had been installed, I hit the "Close" button; I didn't want to make Edge the default browser. However, it appears that a process named "MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe" has appeared in the Task Manager that automatically updates the build of Edge that's currently installed.

Are there currently any known ways in which automatic updates of Edge can be disabled on Windows 7 machines? I've done some rsearch, and most threads online appear to be related to Windows 10.

Comment: The article [How to Disable or Remove MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe Process Running in Task Manager](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-or-remove-microsoftedgeupdate-exe-process-running-in-task-manager/) describes several methods. You will have to try in order to find if they work in Windows 7. Let me know if one (or all) work for you.

Comment: Very useful - thank you. Feel free to suggest as an answer if you like. :)

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE year 2020 : For Windows 10 these methods no longer apply.

---

The article
[How to Disable or Remove MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe Process Running in Task Manager](https://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-or-remove-microsoftedgeupdate-exe-process-running-in-task-manager/)
suggests several methods for getting rid of `MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe`.

**Method 1: Disable Microsoft Edge Update from Startup**

This is done in Task Manager, Startup tab, click on Disable for "Microsoft Edge Update".

**Method 2: Disable Microsoft Edge Update Services**

Open Service Manager and set "Startup type" to Disabled for
"Microsoft Edge Update Service (edgeupdate)" and for
"Microsoft Edge Update Service (edgeupdatem)".

**Method 3: Delete Microsoft Edge Update Scheduled Tasks**

Run Task Scheduler, click on "Task Scheduler Library" and delete or disable
the following tasks:

- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskMachineCore
- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskMachineUA
- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskUserS-1-5-21.......Core
- MicrosoftEdgeUpdateTaskUserS-1-5-21.......UA

**Method 4: Block Microsoft Edge Update Using Firewall**

Use the firewall to disallow internet access to `MicrosoftEdgeUpdate.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked Chromium Edge on two machines here. Updates are Automatic - Same as Google Chrome.

So even though not default, it will update whenever you load it.

It is also a good practice to ensure Edge and Google Chrome are both up to date for security and feature capabilities.

Comment: Umm... security on Windows 7? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-7-end-of-life-support-information , so there are *no* security patches for the OS itself. Updating Edge is like locking the back door, and leaving the front *wide* open.

Comment: There were and are security updates for Windows Browsers pretty much all along.

Answer (score 0):

Open the **Services** in Win 7, you will find there one called:
"**MicrosoftEdgeElevationService**",
which does the following:
"Keeps Microsoft Edge up to update. If this service is disabled, the application will not be kept up to date."
In my case, after installing MS edge (via windows update) this service is deactivated (set on "manual").

You could also instruct your **firewall** on the win7 machine to block the following processes, if they intend to online-connect:

- **microsoftedgeupdatebroker.exe**
- **microsoftedgeupdateondemand.exe**

I just set up my edge on win7, so I don't know so far how this auto-update will behave in the future. In this moment, it behaves politely (is not asking anything).